# Optimising a Mammoth Rider

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, prestige-class, mount

I am new to the optimisation business. However, I often encounter a notion that for a two-handed weapons focused fighter is by the level 20 much more efficient than two weapons fighter.

On the basis of that I would like to create a character that ultimately would become a [Mammoth Rider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/i-m/mammoth-rider). However, I can not (with what little experience I have) decide if my Rider would be better off focusing on charging at enemies over and over again (giving him and the mount one very damaging attack each, every turn) or just parking his mammoth in the fray and going for full-round attack, with mammoth attacking as well (more attacks, but less damage).

For the purpose of this question let's assume that everything else is subject to change (namely race, class taken before progressing to Mammoth Rider, weapon of choice, feat selection, mount selection). The core of the class would basically be usage of Mammoth Rider PRC, focus on mounted combat and enabling the mount to contribute to damage as much as possible without sacrificing overall damage output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Mammoth Riding

Okay, i've gone over this a bunch, and there is a way to do what you want.  It's a bit counterintuitive, but it makes sense.

This class seems designed for either a multiclass druid or any of the classes that get an 'animal companion' at effective druid level -4.  Of those classes, most of them are garbage for doing damage except for one - the **[Mounted Fury Barbarian.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/mounted-fury)**

But it only gets an effective druid level of 6 at level 10, which is lame, and late, and slow, but I was resigned to it after looking at how tenaciously crappy all the other options were until I found this feat, from the Pathfinder Player Companion; [**Boon Companion**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/boon-companion).  At the cost of a feat, it fixes up your animal companion progression, setting you up for a level 7 entry into Mammoth Rider (literally the earliest possible).

Later I also found the [**Mad Dog Barbarian**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/mad-dog), which gets full animal companion and BAB, but delayed rage powers (which is bad, for reasons i'll get to in a second).  It's from the exact same book so.. only take it if you want the fluff.

So you take Mounted Fury Barbarian 6, then enter Mammoth Rider 1, gaining a big-ass mammoth to stomp people.  Which is awesome.  But then you go back and take more Barbarian levels.  Why, after so much trouble?  Because Mammoth Rider doesn't give much after level 1.  It just makes your mammoth a bit tougher, and gives you a d12 HD and +1 BAB per level.

No, instead you want something that comes online at Barbarian 10 - [**Greater Beast Totem**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/beast-totem-greater-su).  While in a Rage, you have Pounce.  Yes, *that* Pounce.  The full-attack-on-a-charge, melee-just-became-able-to-contribute Pounce.  And, with [**Ferocious Mount**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/ferocious-mount-ex) and [**Greater Ferocious Mount**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/ferocious-mount-greater-ex), your Mammoth now has Pounce too.  Of course, this set of Rage powers (**Lesser Beast Totem, Beast Totem, Greater Beast Totem, Ferocious Mount, Greater Ferocious Mount**) is literally every rage power choice between 1st level and 10th, and with the level of mammoth rider, only comes online at level 11.  With Mounted Combat, Power Attack, Ride-By Attack, and Spirited Charge, though, you'll

**break**

### EVERYTHING.

And hell, you wouldn't be playing a Mammoth Rider if you didn't want that.

Comment: Wow. This answer is amazing. Precisely what I needed. Now I need to know more! Can I still use lance during the charge for extra cheese? Will full-round attack routine also count as triple-damage (spirited charge + lance) or just the first one? Finally, having a Mammoth attack with the full routine, would that be a significant portion of my damage or just a small boost?

Comment: Great answer, but I just found a problem.  Mounted Fury Barbarian says *A Medium barbarian can select a camel or a horse. A Small barbarian can select a pony or a wolf, but can also select a boar or a dog if she is at least 8th level.*  Unrelated, you can also give your companion the [Charger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/animal-companion-archetypes/charger-companion-archetype) archetype to make it immune to fatigue.

Comment: There's also [Monstrous Mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/monstrous-mount) and it's upgrade which will let you do it from Griffon-back...

Comment: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/i-m/mammoth-rider - this is the prestige class the OP is referring to.  Check out the first level ability, 'Steed'.  @Bobson

Comment: @eimyr - 1.  Yes.  Pounce gives you more attacks on a charge, it doesn't stop it being 'a charge', so a Lance works.  2. By my understanding, yes, you do triple damage on all your pounce attacks as they are part of the 'charge action'.  3.  Huge size mammoth gets +16 Str compared to Medium elephant/mastodon here http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Elephant-Mastodon so it hits pretty hard in a rage and has 2 attacks to make use of Pounce.  But no.  Your lance will be doing most of the damage.  It is there to TRAMPLE PEOPLE.

Comment: Hm.... but since it shares all passive rage powers, doesn't that mean that the mammoth gets 2 claw attacks on top of his gore and slam, making him do 4 attacks?

Comment: @eimyr - Yep.  I'm writing an edit to my answer that covers this in more detail, including feat selection to enhance smashiness.  If like in 3.5e they could take any feat they qualified for, the smashing would be about 2x as strong, mammoth's inability to take Greater Improved Bull Rush is actually the only thing stopping you taking a total of 12 attacks on the charge between mammoth and rider.

Comment: @walruspride I think Lesnie might be mixing up the skill points of *D&D 3.5* with the skill ranks in *Pathfinder*. Indeed, the character must be at least level 9 before taking levels of mammoth rider because of the 9 ranks required in the Handle Animal and Ride skills. (A *D&D 3.5* character would, however, be able to take as his 7th character level a level in a class with a prerequisite of 9 skill ranks.)

Answer (score 3):

Mammoth Rider is attractive, but you cannot get it at level 7; the earliest possible is at level 10 because of the skill point requirement which require 9 ranks in Handle Animal and 9 in Ride.  Which means in order to qualify you must be level 9 and then take your 10th level in it.

That being said Barbarian isn't the worst way to go regardless.  But you can also take 4 levels of Cavalier (with your teamwork feat being Amplified Rage while being a half-orc), and dipping into Furious Guardian so you get the +6 Str/Con without going to 11 on Barbarian. And obviously get Ferocious Mount.

You can get that boon feat, Beast Rider ('cause half-orc) or Horse Master, to qualify for it by 10.

Answer (score -1):

Try Brawler archetype Wild Child riding a MokeleMbembe. Full druid lvl, many attacks , teamwork feats and mist important free feats at will.
Mokele has trample ability, tail slap Attack, bote and TailWhip that can stun up to 4enemys at a time